# How do I detect if someone has removed my Google Workspace Add-On?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I'm creating a public Google Workspace Add On and I'd like to detect when the add-on has been removed.

I don't see a way to do this in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/overview).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research through [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-workspace-addons) I can confirm that at the date of this answer, there's no option to know when a user has removed your Add-on, either via the Add-On itself or the Google Workspace Marketplace.

This could definitely be a good Feature Request you can submit [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206)